# Как мне проверить количество различных запросов?

Tags: python, requests, cookie, redirect

Я работаю над небольшим проектом, и я хочу написать функцию, которая будет подсчитывать количество запросов в зависимости от адреса ссылки. Если это первый запрос к этому URL-адресу, то значение cookie равно false, а если число запроса превышает 1, то значение равно true, но я столкнулся с проблемой. Моя функция не сбрасывается после изменения URL-адреса; как я могу это исправить?

Мой код:

```
def request_counter(request, request_number=[0]):
    request_number[0]+=1 
    return request_number[0]
```

```
def set_cookie(url: str) -> str:
    try:
        session = requests.Session()
        cookie = requests.cookies.create_cookie(name='unique', value=url, expires=None, domain=url)
        session.cookies.set_cookie(cookie)
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse(e.args)
    return session.cookies.get_dict()
```

```
def get_full_url(url: str, unique: bool) -> str: 
    try:
        link = Links.objects.get(short_url__exact=url)
        if not link.is_active:
            raise KeyError('Ссылка больше недоступна!')
    except Links.DoesNotExist:
        raise KeyError('Попробуйте другую ссылку. Этой нет в базе данных!')
    if not unique:
        link.unique_requests_count +=1
        link.requests_count +=1
        link.save()
    else:
        link.requests_count +=1
        link.save()
    return link.full_url
```

```
def redirection(request, short_url):
    try:
        if request_counter(request) == 1:
            full_link = get_full_url(short_url, False)
        else:
            full_link = get_full_url(short_url, set_cookie(short_url))
        return redirect(full_link)
    except Exception as e: 
        return HttpResponse(e.args)
```

Comment: Вы забыли добавить вызов вашей функции.